# After changing rules for Firewall, how to enable it right now

Tags: windows-7, windows

I found I have to restart the machine, is there a simple way?

Comment: This shouldn't be the case, can you provide more information about the behaviour you are seeing (add to the question).

Comment: I found this is the case

Comment: Are you willing to provide more information or shall we close the question?